# Como salvar e recuperar imagens em base64 usando mongoose em um serviço nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, mongoose, base64

Preciso salvar e recuperar uma imagem em *base64* através de um serviço REST desenvolvido com o NodeJS. Para isso, eu criei o seguinte *schema* no Mongo:

```js
const userSettingsSchema = new Schema(
    {
        'avatar': { type: Buffer, contentType: String, required: false}
    }
);
```

Para persistir a imagem, enviei o código *base64* da imagem (https://www.base64-image.de/) numa requisição post para o serviço passando no corpo da requisição o JSON:

```
{
    "avatar": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j[...]"
}
```

Quando vejo no banco, o avatar é mostrado num formato binário do Buffer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que quando teu tento recuperar a imagem pela api GET, ela retorna com esse valor binário, e não como *base64*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu preciso fazer para obter a imagem em *base64*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode transformar o ArrayBuffer para base64 da seguinte forma

`var base64Image = new Buffer(arrayBuffer, 'binary').toString('base64');`

Onde o arrayBuffer no seu caso seria `documento.avatar.data`